# Drawing an image with Graphics2D

Tags: java, jframe, graphics2d

I am trying to create a game using JFrame, and it requires that I draw images. I am using graphics2D to paint them, but I couldn't figure out why this gave me no output:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);     
    Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/resources/main/my_image");
    g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    g2d.finalize();
}
```

And I haven't been able to find a way to draw an image that actually works.

Comment: Do not ever call `finalize`.

Answer (score 1):

First about "resources/main" (and the missing file extension). If this would happen to be a **maven** project the path should be:

```
src/main/resources/my_image.png
```

For reading a resource file one can do something like:

```
Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/my_image.png"));
```

This file then resides with the classes on the class path, one can check the path, in a jar by unzipping it. *One gets a NullPointerException if the path is incorrect.*

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Your first error might be as stated in the [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html). You shouldn't override `paint()`:

> The `paintComponent` method is where all of your custom painting takes place.

**2.** As per [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/333144/233681) you should also not call `finalize()` on your graphics object, but as far as I can tell, it should not interfere with your drawing. See [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/246083/233681) also for additional details on why `finalize()` is not needed here.

**3.** Did you check that your component is even seen on screen? If it is of size 0x0, the image may be drawn, but still not be seen. One easy way I find to check whether a component is seen, is to (temporarily) change its border to a green line to verify its size and location.

**4.** See [Joop Eggen's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45916356/1654255) answer for resource loading, which could also lead to you not seeing the image.